# "You would have to have had been there" or "You would have to had have been there"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, present-perfect

If the hypothetic question is something like:

> What was it like to live abroad?
>
> What was prison like?
>
> How hectic was your summer camp?

Please specify the grammar of the answer. Past perfect or present perfect, why does it qualify for one and not the other?

Comment: You would have had to have been there.  OR  You would have to have been there.

Comment: Or "You would have had to be there."?

Comment: You cannot use *to had*. When *to* is part of full infinitive, the verb after *to* must be in its base form (present simple). So only "to have" is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The questions are all about the completed past (nothing carrying on into the present), so your answer must be, too.  But you need not use the perfect; any past will do.

> You had to be there
>
> You would have had to be there
>
> You had to have been there
>
> You would have had to have been there
>
> You would have to have been there

All are about the past, and so they all work.