# would have had to vs would have to have been vs would have had to have been

Tags: sentence-construction

1.If I had studied at Harvard University in 2010, I would have had to be diligent in my coursework.

2.If I had studied at Harvard University in 2010, I would have to have been diligent in my coursework.

3.If I had studied at Harvard University in 2010, I would have had to have been diligent in my coursework.

What are the differences between these three sentences in meaning ?

Comment: I think most native speakers would pronounce #1 as *I would have **hat** to be...*, and #2 as *I would **haff** to have been*, which is a clear indication that we think ***those*** occurrences are essentially ***a completely different verb*** (which *doesn't* occur in #3). Knowing that may help you get a handle on these constructions. I can't think of any difference in *meaning*, but #1 (the preferred version, because simplest) is more common than both the two more verbose forms put together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["You would have to have had been there" or "You would have to had have been there"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113909/you-would-have-to-have-had-been-there-or-you-would-have-to-had-have-been-ther)

Comment: The double use of the past perfect in (3) is very awkward, as though the necessity for diligence happened _before_ the university studies.

Comment: My mistake - #3 also includes the "special version" of ***to have*** with the ***must / obligation*** sense with the potentially distinctive pronunciation *I would have **hat** to have been*. It's a bit of a mouthful without contractions, but *I'd've **hat** to've been [**bin**]...* wouldn't particularly stand out as "unusual" in most conversational contexts.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much , I get your point

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for you detailed explanation. I think #2 " I would have to have been diligent in my coursework." may refer to the present because of "I would have to".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your explanation in pronunciation . What I want to focus more is the differences in meaning.

Comment: As stated, *I can't think of any difference in meaning* between your three examples. You should note that the point I was making isn't *actually* about pronunciation. It's about the fact that in the occurrences I flagged up, ***to have*** does actually have a different meaning to *other* occurrences of "the same" verb *in the same sentence*. I just thought it might help you to know that at least *some* native speakers think the difference in meaning is so extreme that we treat the "obligation" usage as "a different verb", with its own distinct pronunciation.